# HTML Agility Issue

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, gecko

I have a the HTML code which I would like to parse.[image]

I have written the code below:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web5 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();


        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc5 = web5.Load("http://www.analytics4.co.uk/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http://www.analytics4.co.uk/pdf.js/pdf/w15639.pdf");
        //var divs5 = doc5.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[id='viewerContainer']").SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("div"));
        // HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc5 = web5.Load("http://google.co.uk");

        HtmlNodeCollection tl = doc5.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='viewerContainer']//div[@id='viewer']//");
        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in tl)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);

        }
```

The result I get for Inner HTML is just

```
    <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
```

and it doesn't make sense. Could anyone explain me how can I go deeper and deeper to the inner divs and so on? Please guys...I need your help.

Comment: As HAP is telling you, they don't exist in the HTTP response.  It sounds like you want to run Javascript.

Comment: That's all there is to start with. The DOM is amended using JavaScript once the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

To go deeper you can use this techniques:

```
    foreach (var node in tl){
        var a = node.ChildNodes[2]; // a is the third child of node
        var b = node.SelectSingleNode("./div[3]"); // b is the third "div"
            // element in node children. The "./" in XPath means "from current node"
    }
```

Good luck!